# Facebook Page Plugin is not working - only for one site

Tags: php, facebook, plugins, facebook-page

I have integrated the page plugin in my directory.

ruhrlink.de info.php?schluessel=150991 dont work, others do.

When I enter the web adress manually in the developers site -> Page plugin 
it dont works there, too.

https://www.facebook.com/Geschirr-Service-Ch-Dittrich-607545982758149/

What is so special with this adress?

Answer (score 0):

The page has some sort of access restriction set. The page plugin only works for public pages without any restrictions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#privacy:

> **Privacy Restricted Pages**
>   Facebook Pages with privacy restrictions cannot be embedded.

Comment: They make dishes Renatl. A restrictiin is not logical. But I will ask the owner. Its a pity that there is no error message.

Comment: Logical or not, there’s definitively some restriction in place - I can request details for `/607545982758149` with my user access token, but with an app access token it gives the “unsupported GET request …” error message. And that is a very sure indicator that there are restrictions, so check with the page admin.