# Check if Facebook page (used within iframe site plugin) is a Privacy Restricted Page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Plugins of some facebook pages cannot be embedded. Some reason seems to be offensiv content the other reason is a privacy restricted page. (Here is a similar question
[Facebook Page Plugin is not working - only for one site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140342/facebook-page-plugin-is-not-working-only-for-one-site))

One plugin is the site plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#privacy

How to check if page is restricted to not show a empty iframe?

Here is an example iframe I want to replace (jquery) with an image or paragraph, because the loaded iframe is empty because the page is restricted.

```js
 (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var bh = 0;
$(".holder").css('width', $("#ReinekeFuchsCologneEVENTS").css("width"));
$(".bar").css('width', $("#ReinekeFuchsCologneEVENTS").css("width")); 
bh = $("#ReinekeFuchsCologne").css('height');$(".bar").css('height', bh); $("#ReinekeFuchsCologneEVENTS").hide(); $("#ReinekeFuchsCologneCLICK").css('width', $("#ReinekeFuchsCologneEVENTS").css("width")); $("#ReinekeFuchsCologneCLICK").click(function s(){ $("#ReinekeFuchsCologne").toggle();            $("#ReinekeFuchsCologneEVENTS").toggle();
            $("#ReinekeFuchsCologneCLICK").css('height', bh);
     });     
         });
```

```css
.bar{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
 #  left:0;
    width:100%;
   height:100%;
  opacity: 0.2;}
.bar:hover{
    background: red;
  }
.bar:after {
    content: "Here should be appear the content of iframe of the Facebook Page or an alternativ error splash screen";
    }
.holder{
vertical-align: top; 
    white-space: normal; 
     float: left;
    position:relative;
}
.frame{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background :blue;
}
.container{
 display: inline-block;  }
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  
  <div class="holder">
 <iframe id="ReinekeFuchsCologneEVENTS" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpg%2FReinekeFuchsCologne&tabs=events&width=500&height=499&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=false&appId" width="500" height="499" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
 
  <div id="ReinekeFuchsCologneCLICK" class="bar"></div>
 <iframe id="ReinekeFuchsCologne" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FReinekeFuchsCologne%2F&tabs&width=500&height=70&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=false&appId" width="500" height="70" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
 
</div><!--end of Holder-->
```

Comment: I don’t think there is a way for you to determine that. The JS SDK events do not cover this, and the Same Origin Policy is preventing you from checking anything inside that iframe using scripting from your end. The plugin even loads with a 200 OK response code in such cases, so even an error event handler on the iframe element itself won’t do. The only way would be an API request for the page name or ID - but that would only work, if you had an app that had Page Public Content Access feature approved.